# NAS file transfers stuck at 11mb/s

Tags: nas, file-transfer, data-transfer

Can anybody tell me why two different desktops get stuck transferring files at 11mb/s to and from the NAS? If both desktops are transferring our speeds from to 5mbs/s each.

I was using a Dlink NAS but now use an old Dell running Windows 10 with the same issue. I'm using wd green drives that max out at about 90mb/s sequential reads and writes. I've also used a different router now and I'm still having the issue.

Is this just a windows issue?

Comment: Sounds like a 100Mbps connection being maxed out somewhere...